# Is there a way to export GTA San Andreas game stats to a file?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I want to export my game stats.

I know I can access them in the pause menu, but I want to export them to a file, where I can then use them for a personal project where I can track progresses.

Comment: I can't think of a game that does this natively.  Maybe with mods?

Comment: Well, they're currently saved somewhere... If you can find the file the game saves those in, you can read them out. It's possible they encrypt them in the save file itself (but I have **no** idea what they do for sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can .There is an option to export to file game stats.
It is exported to one of the following directories:

- `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\GTA San Andreas User Files`
- `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\GTA San Andreas User Files`

After you export to a file, it will be stored in the above mentioned directory, and named as `stats.html`. User files are also stored in this folder.